# Unsung Hero Gold Badge

Tags: support, feature-request

I was wondering if there is any way I can check number of accepted answers I posted so that I can calculate how near I am to get **Unsung Hero** gold badge.

**Edit**

I also noticed it doesn't count answers that one answered on there own questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: the real requirements:

- Have more than ten accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 25% of all your accepted answers
- Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered
- Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations

---

You have two ways.

First: search for

> user:me isaccepted:1 votes:0

This will display only your 0 votes accepted answers. Then do your math from there. Since you also need to take in account days, you may want to add a "created:" somewhere

> created:2012-03..2012-04 (created between 2012-03-01 and 2012-04-30)

Other option:

use this query [How Unsung am I?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66537/how-unsung-am-i). Notice that you will query old data by design, so any result you get won't be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your profile and click the answers link... and count them... which is less than ideal.

Comment: I went to my profile several times intended to count them but just gave up on first page Lol.

Comment: @MuhammadRaja - this post on the main meta site refers to an app that displays badge advancements. Never used it, so I don't know if the Unsung hero badge is included. Link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137960/171199

Comment: @SPArchaeologist thanks, this App is actually helpful but just to confirm it doesn't calculate Unsung Hero Gold Badge.

Comment: @MuhammadRaja - yea, I already suspected it. Ok. Let's try something different.